# Error: 400 (bad request) using fetch to POST data to a local server

Tags: javascript, post, fetch, http-status-code-400

I am using fetch to POST data that I collect from a form to a local server. The problem is that I receive an "error: 400 (bad request)" and I have no idea why. the server is up and running correctly and I can successfully GET data from it.

Am I using fetch in a wrong way ?

```
async function handleFetch(payload) {
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order';
    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: payload
    }
    response = await fetch(url, options);
    return (response);
}
```

```
function handleForm(orderList) {
    const form = document.getElementById('order');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let contact = new Contact(form.surname.value, form.name.value, form.adress.value, form.city.value, form.mail.value);
        let order = JSON.stringify({ contact, orderList });
        const response = await handleFetch(order);
        const data = response.json();

        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

the data I'm sending is a contact object with en item list (which is just JSON.stringify and sent as body):

```
{"contact":{"surname":"Tom","name":"Bombadil","adress":"123 The Shire","city":"MiddleEarth","mail":"Tom.bomb@gmail.com"},"orderList":[{"colors":["Tan","Chocolate","Black","White"],"_id":"5be9c8541c9d440000665243","name":"Norbert","price":2900,"imageUrl":"http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_1.jpg","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."},{"colors":["Pale brown","Dark brown","White"],"_id":"5beaa8bf1c9d440000a57d94","name":"Arnold","price":3900,"imageUrl":"http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_2.jpg","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."},{"colors":["Brown"],"_id":"5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95","name":"Lenny and Carl","price":5900,"description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.","imageUrl":"http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_3.jpg"}]}
```

Info from Chrome inspector :

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order 400 (Bad Request)

Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order"
```

Comment: How is your server configured to handle `POST` requests on the route `/api/teddies/order`?

Comment: Hi, esqew ! Your comment prompted me to go have a look at the server code rather than read the doc. There I found out that it is sending me the bad request upon bad formating of my packet (tag name). So I made the modifications and it work fine now. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right dirrection !